# Show a second window from a second .xib file in Xcode?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

I am a complete noob with Xcode, but I am trying to make a small Mac application.
What I want happen, is that I press a button in the main window, and another window opens on top of that main window. 
As I said, I am a complete noob, so I would prefer a step by step guide :)

Answer (score 2):

It is quite simple, first of all you have to create a window with Xcode, then a WindowController after that you can link the Controller with your view(the Xib). 
Then to open up a new window (lets say your window controller is called YourWindowController) just insert this code in the IBAction method that get fired by your button :

```
YourWindowController *controllerWindow = 
[[YourWindowController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"You_Window_XIB"];
[controllerWindow showWindow:self];
```

Comment: I am afraid I still don't get it... This is what I have tried so far:

1. file -> new -> file -> cocoa -> Objective-C class -> class: [name], subclass of: NSWindowController.  

2. Connect the button to the AppDelegate.h so that I get - (IBAction)addClient:(id)sender; in the header file and - (IBAction)addClient:(id)sender {} in the AppDelegate.m file.  

3. Add your code to the (IBAction)addClient:etc. in the AppDelegate.m file.

It is not working, I got a lot of errors at the code you gave me...

I think I may need a more step-by-step type of explanation :b